# Community Headline Component

Tags: community, headline-component

This might be a silly question, but it's driving me nuts.

I am configuring a lightning community using "Customer Service" Template and is using Headline component on the home page.

By default it says "Welcome !!", as shown in the below image.

[image]

Is there a way to personalise it with current logged in user's Name? I tried using {!$User.FirstName}, but no result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct approach. You can create a custom ligntning component like this: 
Cmp:

```
 <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="testCommCon">
    <aura:attribute name="Name" type="String"/> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
    <div class="ui-widget" data-component-label="Headline" data-allow-move="true" data-allow-select="true" data-allow-rte="false"  data-allow-delete="true">
    <section class="forceCommunityHeadline" data-aura-class="forceCommunityHeadline">
    <h1 class="headlineTitle">
    <span class="headlineTitleText" >
    <span class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">
        {!v.Name}
    </span>
    </span>
    </h1>
    <p class="headlineInfo">
    </p>
    </section>
    </div>
    </aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
({
doInit: function(cmp){
    var action = cmp.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.Name", response.getReturnValue());
         } 
      }); 
       $A.enqueueAction(action);
     }
 })
```

And class:

```
public with sharing class testCommCon{
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String getUserName() {
    return userinfo.getName();
  }
 }
```

Then, from the community builder, just add the newly created component to the layout. Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write {!Currentuser.name} in the Title of the Headline component.